# How to get a Windows App installed on multiple clients to access Azure Vault when the secret or certificate expires every 1-2 years

Tags: windows, azure, client, azure-keyvault

First, I'm not too much knowledgeable in Azure App Service and I'm looking for advices.

I'm building a Windows application that will require a secret stored in Azure Vault. The application will be installed at various clients. I would like to centralize the secret into Vault so that when I need to update the secret, all clients get the new version of the secret and there is no disruption of service. I don't want to go to the various clients every 2 years to renew the client secret or every year to renew a certificate.

How can I achieve this? How can a Windows application that will be installed at various locations across the country and be used for over 10 years can get a secret from Vault without having to visit those clients every 2 years to renew the client secret?

Comment: to access this secret's storage apps also need some kind of password/cert, otherwise it will be unsecured, right? so you will need to have some access and update mechanism for secrets which are used to access to secrets...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of application is this? Something a user will open or unattended/background application?

If a user will open the application, you could use the user flow authentication and implement a custom API which will return the secret using e.g. Azure B2C Authentication. In this case, no secret is needed on the client - just the app id and the user authentication on top.

In case of an unattended Application, it gets quite more complicated as you need to somehow manage individual identities or at least secrets for those clients. As if any of those secrets gets exposed (which is quite easy as the client has knowledge of the secret) you would need to regenerate those.

One Certificate per client would work, but this of course is a lot of effort in managing it (generation, revocation, renew).

Also keep in mind the limits of an App Registration in regards of how many secrets you could create
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39816